# How to clear form fields onSubmit in Meteor using Uniforms

Tags: javascript, mongodb, forms, reactjs, meteor

I am using [Uniforms](https://github.com/vazco/uniforms) to create a form field for my site. When I click the submit button after filling out the form field, the data is submitted to the database but the fields are still left populated instead of emptying upon submission. I tried creating an `onSubmit` method (i think that's what it is called...still new) that would go to the schema and edit the value string `'Song name'.uniforms.value = ''` but the console is stating that I cannot set property 'value' of undefined.

Here is my form code:

```
const PostCreateForm = ({model}) =>
    <AutoForm
      schema={PostSchema}
      onSubmit={
        (doc => Submissions.insert(doc))
        & ('Song name'.uniforms.value = '')
      }
      model={model}
      placeholder={true}>

        <AutoField name="Song name" />

        <div className="super-special-class">
            <SubmitField className="super-special-class-with-suffix" />
        </div>
    </AutoForm>
;
```

My schema code:

```
const PostSchema = new SimpleSchema({

    'Song name': {
      type: String,
      min: 1,
      uniforms: {
        placeholder: '',
        value: ''
      }
    }
  });
```

And finally the class where I call the `<PostCreateForm/>`

```
  export default class UniformsHello extends React.Component {

    render() {

      return(
        <div>
          <h1>Submit a track</h1>
          <PostCreateForm />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Should I be calling an onSubmit for this, or maybe a full on page refresh? Which is the better option and how would I go about this? Thanks!!